# QT: how to Implement the hover card outside the window

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

[image]

How to simulate a similar effect, I tried qmenu, but it is modal, synchronous, not compatible with leaveEvent, it is very troublesome to operate, does QT have a native method? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by not compatible with leave event? It is a QWidget, so it is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The menu will block the main program, forcing the leaveevent to be triggered